# A slideup div using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div that is 250px tall and 160px wide. When the page is loaded the div will be hidden behind the content except for 30px. I am wondering how to make the div clickable so it will slideup to reveal the entire div. Thanks in advance.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#maininfo').click(function() {
                $('.maininfo_tab').slideUp('slow', function() {
                // Animation complete.
             });
           });
</script>
    <div id="maininfo">
        <div class="maininfo_tab" style="position:relative;margin-bottom:35px;">
```

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the animate method to slide it and the click event to wire it up:

```
var nextHeight = 250;
$("#myDiv").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: nextHeight
    });
    nextHeight = Math.abs(nextHeight - 280);
});​
```

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/qu5bz/8/

Comment: The maininfo_tab is an image I need to move as a whole up and down.